# How to read data from a JSON object(in a file) into R?

Tags: json, r

I am new to R and do not have much exposure to programming. I am having a problem loading a file(contains JSON object) into R.

```
> library(rjson)
> jsonFile <- "C:\\Users\\jsonRecords.txt"
> jsonData <- fromJSON( jsonFile, method = "C", unexpected.escape = "error" )
Error in fromJSON(jsonFile, method = "C", unexpected.escape = "error") : 
  unexpected character 'C'
```

I wanted the data to be read into R for further analysis.. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at `rjson`   http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html

Comment: fromJSON( json_str, file, method = "C", unexpected.escape = "error" )   This is all it has in the Reference.pdf for importing data into R

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try just this:

```
    fromJSON( file = json_file )
```

It will read all the file. here an example:

```
write(toJSON( iris ),'jstest')
res <- fromJSON( file="jstest")

str(res)
List of 5
 $ Sepal.Length: num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num [1:150] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : chr [1:150] "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

Answer (score 5):

it looks like all you are missing is the `file=` argument

```
fromJSON( file = json_file, method = "C", unexpected.escape = "error" )
```

---

if you look at `args(fromJSON)`

```
 > args(fromJSON)
 function (json_str, file, method = "C", unexpected.escape = "error")
```

you'll see that the first argument is `json_str` and the second is `file`. Since you are only supplying the second argument, you must tell the function explicitly what it is you are giving it.   *(Otherwise, it thinks that your `json_file` string is a json object and it will try to treat it as such.. hence the error.)*

Comment: Yes I corrected and ran the command again but still it gives the same error          > jsonFile <- "C:\\Users\\jsonRecords.txt"
> jsonData <- fromJSON( jsonFile, method = "C", unexpected.escape = "error" )
Error in fromJSON(jsonFile, method = "C", unexpected.escape = "error") : 
  unexpected character 'C'

Comment: Try with another file, perhaps an example www.json.org   If then you have no error, then there might be something in the file causing the problem.  Can you post the file online?